# Sending E-mail when JBoss eap 6.3 server is downn

Tags: java, jboss, server, jmx, jboss6.x

I want to send the email notification to the admin when JBoss server is down.Kindly suggest the best way to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, maybe not the ideal answer...
You could implement a dedicated standalone process that periodically sends a request to your JBoss (e.g. a known index.html of an application deployed on the server), then sends a notification depending on the returned response's HTTP code.